# @babel/preset-env loaded with wrong babel version after upgrade babel 6 to 7

Tags: babeljs, babel-plugin, babel-preset-env

I tried to upgrade my babel from 6 to 7, but I encounter this issue.

```
/Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:328
        throw e;
        ^

Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel. (While processing preset: "/Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
    at throwVersionError (/Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:65:11)
    at Object.assertVersion (/Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:13:11)
    at _default (/Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:154:7)
    at /Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
    at /Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:317:46
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
    at compile (/Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:103:45)
    at loader (/Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/darryl/Documents/Github/apps/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Can someone help to explain what had happened?
I tried to remove node_modules and package-lock.json, and also run `npm cache clean --force`

But this error still occured.
How to force this dependency (@babel/preset-env) to use Babel 7 in their dependency instead of Babel 6.26.3?

Comment: The stack trace still mentions `babel-register` which is Babel 6. You'd need to use `@babel/register`.

Comment: This is weird, I couldn't find this babel-register in my package.json as deps, is this a dependency of other dependency? Do I need to install it in my project then?

Comment: Seems it works fine after I install `@babel/register`, thanks @loganfsmyth !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth), do

```
npm i -D @babel/register
```

help me to solve the issue I encounter about this `babel-register` dependency that still using Babel version 6.